# Add/show each row by unique ID

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to show each hidden row using the same button. When the user clicks add+ to display another hidden row. If that makes since.

I'm using this script to hide all table rows except the first one.

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js'></script>
 
 
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('tr#row2, tr#row3, tr#row4, tr#row5, tr#row6, tr#row7, tr#row8, tr#row9, tr#row10, tr#row11').hide();
 });
  </script>


</script>
```

When the button (#add) is clicked once, if the row is not visible show next row 
otherwise remain hidden. This works well for displaying one table. How would I 
go about displaying the rest of the tables like this one without spitting them all out at once? I would like them displayed one by one.

```js
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#add").click(function () {
   if ($('tr#row2:visible').length==0)
   {
     $('tr#row2').show();
     $("#add").attr('value','Remove');
   }
   else{
     $('tr#row2').hide();
     $("#add").attr('value','Add');
   }
 });
</script>
```

The rest of the code looks something like this and each row has a different ID.
Any Ideas?

```html
<table width="200" border="6">

<input id="add" type="button" value="Add" style="width:70px"/>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row4">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row5">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think i kind of see what you want to do, could you check your description and see if you can't explain it more clearly. I think you want to show each row one at a time and possibly use a re-usable function. does that sound right to you? Lastly welcome :D

Comment: That sounds pretty spot on. I will update my description right away. Thanks~!

Comment: First off, I would add JQuery to your tags. Second, you're saying you want to incrementally show the next row with the button click, but you're also changing your button text to "Remove". So I assume you also want to be able to remove rows as well? If that's the case, you'll need either two buttons - one for adding, one for removing, or an Add button and a remove button for each row that appears only when that row is displayed. Does any of this sound like what you're going for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this isn't what you're after let me know and I'll see if I can't help you out. At least It may give you some ideas.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var currentRow = 2;
    var previousRow = null;
    var defaultRowNumber = 2; // constant: For when we need to reset current row value.
    var resetRowNumberOn = 7; // constant: This looks odd but it's how the function and math works together.


    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('tr#row2, tr#row3, tr#row4, tr#row5, tr#row6, tr#row7, tr#row8, tr#row9, tr#row10, tr#row11').hide();

        $("#add").click(function () {
            ShowHideRow(currentRow)
        });

        var ShowHideRow = function (rowNumber) {

            if ($('tr#row' + rowNumber + ' :visible').length == 0) {
                $('tr#row' + rowNumber).show();
                $("#add").attr('value', 'Remove');
            }
            else {
                $("#add").attr('value', 'Add');
            }

            if (typeof previousRow === 'number')
                $('tr#row' + (previousRow)).hide();

            previousRow = currentRow;
            currentRow++;

            if (currentRow === resetRowNumberOn) {
                currentRow = defaultRowNumber;
                $('tr#row' + (previousRow)).hide();
                previousRow = null;
            }            
        }
    });

</script>

<table width="200" border="6">

    <input id="add" type="button" value="Add" style="width:70px" />
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>1&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>2&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
        <td>3&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row4">
        <td>4&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row5">
        <td>5&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The form displays only up to the second row and now takes multiple clicks to remove. I will keep trying. Thanks for the ideas~!

Comment: Sorry mate sounds like I've misunderstood what you after.

Comment: Do you want to show each row yet not hide previous?

Comment: Yes, this way the user can add the amount of fields they need.

Comment: Sorry for all of the edits :)  So I got it to work! - took me a while. All I had to change was the following line: if (typeof previousRow === 'number')
                $('tr#row' + (previousRow)).hide(); to .show(); and it works. Thanks for your help man~!